# adding Zend_Form_Element_Captcha to form causes form to not display

Tags: zend-framework

I am having trouble getting a captcha element to display in a signup form. It was working previously, but now for some reason when I try to add the captcha element to the form the entire form does not display.

Below is the function in my controller file to create the form

```
private function getSignupForm()
{
  // create form
  $form = new Zend_Form();      
  $form->setAction('success');
  $form->setMethod('post');
  $form->setAttrib('sitename', 'loudbite');

  // add elements
  require "form/elements.php";
  $loudbiteElements = new Elements();

  // create username field
  $form->addElement($loudbiteElements->getUsernameTextField());

  // create email field
  $form->addElement($loudbiteElements->getEmailTextField());

  // create password field
  $form->addElement($loudbiteElements->getPasswordTextField());

  // add captcha
  $form->addElement($loudbiteElements->getCaptcha());

  // create submit button
  $form->addElement('submit', 'submit');
  $submitElement = $form->getElement('submit');
  $submitElement->setLabel('Create My Account!');

  return $form;
}
```

and here is the action to pass the form to the corresponding view

```
public function newAction()
{
    // get the form
    $form = $this->getSignupForm();

    // add the form to the view
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

If I comment out the line in my getSignupForm() function where I add the captcha to the form then the form will display ok minus the captcha element. This leads me to assume that there is a problem with the captcha contruction.

Below is the function in an external model file where the captcha is constructed

```
public function getCaptcha()
{
    $captchaElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha(
      'signup',
      array('captcha' => array(
        'captcha' => 'Figlet',
        'wordLen' => 6,
        'timeout' => 600))
    );
    $captchaElement->setLabel('Please type in the words below to continue:');

    return $captchaElement;
}
```

All the other form elements are created in this external model file. Based on the fact that the other elements display correctly if I do not add the captcha element, I assume it is not a problem with accessing the model file.

The last time I used this signup form everything was working ok! And I don't remember having changed anything between then and now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Roan